# Cosmos stored procedure partition key error when trying to update an item

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to write a procedure that logs that an Item was retrieved when the procedure is used. Right now, I can retrieve the items but I am just stuck on adding a single key and value to the item as I loop through the collection:

Here is my code:

```
function example(prefix) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
collection.chain().filter(function (doc) {
    return doc.textStatus = "delivered";
}).map(function (doc) {
    doc.note = "test";
    var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(doc._self, doc, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("replaceDocument(metaItem) returned false.");

}).value();}
```

This is giving me this message:

> Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error: {"Errors":["Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted."]}

I have also tried setting the partition key of the doc (e.g. doc.partitionKey = "sid"), though I would assume it is set as the docs are being pulled from the collect.

### Update

I thought that is code was sending docs to map function but when I checked again, it was not. I thought that my partition key was "/sid" or "sid" and entered those as strings for parameters of the stored procedure. This was after adding === and sid on filters. This produced no errors, but I could not log or change any docs.

[image: Showing top of collection list]

[image: Showing where partition key is entered for stored procedure]

Answer (score 1):

Please change  `return doc.textStatus = "delivered";` to `return doc.textStatus == "delivered" && doc.partitionKey == "sid";` to have a try. It works for me.

[image]

**Update**

When you want to execute your SP, you need to pass your partition key value not your partition key path. According to your screenshot, your partition key path is `/sid` and your partition key value is `undefined`.

So your SP should be like this:

```
function example(partition_key_value) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    if(!partition_key_value){
        partition_key_value = undefined;
    }
    collection.chain().filter(function (doc) {
        return doc.textStatus == "delivered" && doc.sid== partition_key_value;
    }).map(function (doc) {
        doc.note = "test";
        var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(doc._self, doc,function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("replaceDocument(metaItem) returned false.");
    }).value();
}
```

And execute your SP like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. When I added an = in the partionKey condition, it executed without error... but there there was no change to the doc.note field.

Comment: Have you tried  `console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));` within  `map`  function. Can you get any output?

Comment: I could swear I was getting output, but I guess that I am not. See my update above. I have no idea how to verify what my partition key is.

Comment: @JakeDurell Sorry for so late to reply you. I have updated my answer. You can have a try.